# PCL - Glib Compiling from source, FFI linking

Tags: compiler-construction, glib, ffi, point-cloud-library

I need to install PCL (point cloud library) on a Linux server without root access. Then I downloaded the source and checked for dependences. And here we go...

These are the dependencies I've found:

```
PCL
--BOOST
----ZLIB
----BZIP
--EIGEN
--FLANN
----HDF5
----LIBUSB
------UDEV
--------GLIB
----------LIBFFI
----------ZLIB 
--VTK
```

I need to compile glib from source. Glib requires FFI libraries so I downloaded them, compiled and installed them in

```
/home/franz/Downloads/libffi-3.0.13/installed
```

then I set these variables:

```
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/franz/Downloads/libffi-3.0.13/installed/lib
    LIBFFI_CFLAGS="-I/home/franz/Downloads/libffi-3.0.13/installed/lib/libffi-3.0.13/include" LIBFFI_LIBS="-lffi -L/home/franz/Downloads/libffi-3.0.13/installed/lib"
```

then ./configure and make. I got these errors:

```
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/franz/Downloads/glib-2.37.5/gobject'
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=missing-prototypes -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=init-self -Werror=format-security -Werror=format=2 -Werror=missing-include-dirs -g -O2   -o gobject-query gobject-query.o ./libgobject-2.0.la ../glib/libglib-2.0.la 
libtool: link: gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=missing-prototypes -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=init-self -Werror=format-security -Werror=format=2 -Werror=missing-include-dirs -g -O2 -o .libs/gobject-query gobject-query.o  ./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so -L/home/franz/Downloads/libffi-3.0.13/installed/lib /home/franz/Downloads/glib-2.37.5/glib/.libs/libglib-2.0.so ../glib/.libs/libglib-2.0.so -lpthread -lrt -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/franz/Downloads/glib-2.37.5/installed/lib
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_void'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_double'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_prep_cif'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_sint32'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_float'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_uint64'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_sint64'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_pointer'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_uint32'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_call'
```

then I saw the libraries I wanted to include and setted with LIBFFI_CFLAGS/LIBS in configure are not present in make, so I changed my CC variable to force my compiler to use my libraries:

```
LIBFFI_CFLAGS="-I/home/franz/Downloads/libffi-3.0.13/installed/lib/libffi-3.0.13/include" LIBFFI_LIBS="-lffi -L/home/franz/Downloads/libffi-3.0.13/installed/lib" ZLIB_CFLAGS="-I/home/franz/Downloads/zlib-1.2.8/installed/include" ZLIB_LIBS="-L/home/franz/Downloads/zlib-1.2.8/installed/lib" CC="gcc $LIBFFI_CFLAGS $LIBFFI_LIBS" CXX="/usr/bin/g++-4.4 $LIBFFI_CFLAGS $LIBFFI_LIBS" ./configure --prefix=`pwd`/installed
```

and make

In this way instead of gcc in the make process, we'll get gcc -I... -lffi -L...
And this worked so far. But now I get the same error in another location:

```
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/franz/Downloads/glib-2.37.5/gio'
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -I/home/franz/Downloads/libffi-3.0.13/installed/lib/libffi-3.0.13/include -lffi -L/home/franz/Downloads/libffi-3.0.13/installed/lib -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=missing-prototypes -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=init-self -Werror=format-security -Werror=format=2 -Werror=missing-include-dirs -g -O2   -o gio-querymodules gio-querymodules.o ../glib/libglib-2.0.la ../gobject/libgobject-2.0.la ../gmodule/libgmodule-2.0.la libgio-2.0.la 

libtool: link: gcc -I/home/franz/Downloads/libffi-3.0.13/installed/lib/libffi-3.0.13/include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=missing-prototypes -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=init-self -Werror=format-security -Werror=format=2 -Werror=missing-include-dirs -g -O2 -o .libs/gio-querymodules gio-querymodules.o  -L/home/franz/Downloads/libffi-3.0.13/installed/lib ../glib/.libs/libglib-2.0.so ../gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.so ../gmodule/.libs/libgmodule-2.0.so ./.libs/libgio-2.0.so -L/home/franz/Downloads/zlib-1.2.8/installed/lib /home/franz/Downloads/glib-2.37.5/gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.so /home/franz/Downloads/glib-2.37.5/gmodule/.libs/libgmodule-2.0.so -ldl /home/franz/Downloads/glib-2.37.5/glib/.libs/libglib-2.0.so -lpthread -lrt /home/franz/Downloads/libffi-3.0.13/installed/lib/../lib/libffi.so -lresolv -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/franz/Downloads/glib-2.37.5/installed/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/franz/Downloads/libffi-3.0.13/installed/lib/../lib
../gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_void'
../gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_double'
../gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_prep_cif'
../gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_sint32'
../gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_float'
../gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_uint64'
../gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_sint64'
../gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_pointer'
../gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_uint32'
../gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_call'
```

The problem is that in this case the libraries are present (you can see `-lffi -L<ffi_libs_path>` but the error look the same as before).

Any idea how to get this work? I repeat I cannot install libraries because I cannot have root access. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

use

`export LIBFFI_LIBS="-L/your/path/to-ffi libraries/ -lffi"`

Answer (score -1):

after ./configure you can edit your Makefile
find the "LIBFFI_LIBS=...",and add "-lffi" at the end.
like "LIBFFI_LIBS=-L/work/opencv-static/libffi-3.2.1/output/lib -lffi"